# Extrinsic curvature in Bowen-York initial data (Exercise 3.11 in Baumgarte)

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

How can I get from:
$$
\overline{A}_L^{ij} = \frac{6}{r^3} l^{(i} \overline{\epsilon}^{j)kl} J_k l_l
$$
(where $l^i \equiv \frac{x^i}{r}$) and
$$
W^r = 0, \; W^\theta = 0, \; W^\phi = -\frac{J}{r^3}
$$
that:
$$
\overline{A}^L_{r \phi} = \frac{3 J}{r^2} \sin^2 \theta.
$$

I've checked it several times, but my answer is with the $r \phi$ indices upstairs:
$$
\overline{A}_L^{r \phi} = \frac{3 J}{r^2} \sin^2 \theta.
$$

Later he uses it in $\overline{A}_L^{ij} \overline{A}^L_{ij}$ which comes out very different for these two definitions.

---

*Context*:

In the textbook Baumgarte decomposes the traceless extrinsic curvature ($\overline{A}_{ij} \equiv K_{ij} - \overline{\gamma}_{ij} K$) into transverse-traceless and longitudinal components:
$$
\overline{A}^{ij} = \overline{A}^{ij}_L + \overline{A}^{ij}_{TT},
$$
takes the gauge where $\overline{A}_{TT}^{ij} = 0$ and uses following ansantz to define the longitudinal part in terms of the vector $W^i$:
$$
\overline{A}_L^{ij} = \overline{D}^i W^j + \overline{D}^j W^i - \frac{2}{3} \overline{\gamma}^{ij} \overline{D}_k W^k.
$$

Comment: I have traced it down to this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9710096.pdf . See formula (6) there. Nevertheless it is pretty odd that the author of the paper works with vectors, but gets the K with lower indices.